# Javascript: onchange or addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, onchange, addeventlistener

I am totally new to Javascript. But I learned a little about Activescript before. I was taught to use addEventListener to handle events.

But when I come to JavaScript, although addEventListener is an option, it seems a minor way to use addEventListener. Instead, people use onChange().

Except syntactically, are there any behavioural differences?

I was also taught to always use removeEventListener. It seems not very necessary. If I use onChange, there is no need to code removeEventListener?

Thank you

Comment: To learn about the differences and much more, have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 15):

Two main differences :

- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) isn't compatible with old IE browsers
- onchange doesn't add an event listener : it replaces the existing one

Comment: The second bullet isn't quite true. `onchange` will replace event handlers set with `onchange`, but will not replace those set with `addEventListener` (tested in IE11, Firefox, and Chrome) Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ThatMatthew/ksngmpy3/

Answer (score 3):

With `addEventListener` you can attach multiple event listeners. This is not true of the `onchange` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

> ### Docs
>
> [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) and [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) are both event attributes in HTML that
> are used to capture user interactions with form elements, but they
> differ in terms of when they trigger and what kind of interactions
> they respond to.
>
> #### 1) oninput Event
>
> - The oninput event is triggered whenever the value of an input element changes. This includes any change in the input, whether it's
>   due to typing, pasting, or using arrow keys to change the value.
> - It provides real-time feedback as it triggers immediately when the user is actively interacting with the input field.
>
> ##### Example with inline listener
>
> ```js
> const updateValue = (value) => {
>   console.log(`value changed: ${value}`);
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <input type="text" oninput="updateValue(this.value)">
> ```
>
> #### 2) onchange Event:
>
> - The onchange event is triggered when the value of an input element is changed and the element loses focus (i.e., when the user clicks
>   outside the input or presses the Tab key to move to the next field).
> - It is not triggered until the user has finished making changes and moved away from the input.
>
> ##### Example with inline listener
>
> ```js
> const updateValue = (value) => {
>   console.log(`value changed: ${value}`);
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <input type="text" onchange="updateValue(this.value)">
> ```
>
> #### Summary
>
> In summary, if you want to capture every change in real-time, use
> oninput. If you prefer to wait until the user has finished making
> changes and the input loses focus, use onchange. The choice between
> them depends on the specific behavior you want for your application.
> Additionally, oninput is often preferred for immediate feedback
> scenarios like live character counting or instant validation.

### On*X* vs AddEventListener syntax

As this article from Medium points out:
"[Use addEventListener() Instead of onclick/oninput/onchange... Especially When Working in Teams](https://medium.com/@ysmiracle/use-addeventlistener-instead-of-onclick-oninput-onchange-especially-when-working-in-teams-50ad40badb8d)"

#### Summary

Using addEventListener(‘*EventName*’, …) we can have multiple listeners on one event, whereas using on*EventName* we can only assign one listener to one event (which is always the latest assigned listener). Since using addEventListener() doesn’t replace other listeners attached on the same event, it is much safer to use this than the onclick/oninput/onchange… event, as we won’t accidentally replace someone else’s previously attached listeners

Comment: Why is it better though? I'm not sure if it's part of your point, but relying on `nextSibling` twice like this seems very brittle and could easily break while making small changes to the markup. I'd prefer to add a class or id and use a selector rather than assume the output is exactly 2 siblings away.

Comment: You can do exactly the same with onchange

Comment: Since its introduction in 2013, this question has witnessed considerable evolution, especially as we approach 2024. Reflecting on the past, the initial question diverged significantly from its 2021-modified counterpart. Originally, the challenge revolved around the inability to modify the HTML source for JavaScript, ruling out the use of class or id for this particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

All said by you all is true, but when change is made "by code", only onchange seems to capture the change.

Comment: This is invalid, no idea where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, depends on your use-case:

use onchange when you want to replace all current listeners and you're sure you won't be adding new ones.

use addEventListener when you might want more than one

```
  const els = document.getElementsByClassName("input-field")
  for (const el of els) {
    // choose one
    el.onchange = (e) => eventInputChanged(e)
    el.addEventListener("change", eventInputChanged)
  }
```